# to post then send then retrieve a value

Tags: jquery

First i want to display a list of products selected from a database in Gallery.html . I make it with:

```
$('#div').load(galleryshow.php)
```

This php page echo each item with a form when i submit it(from Gallery.html ), it shows specific item at (Product-Details.html) with details. To do this item the first php page(galleryshow.php) (it echo submit button at gallery .html) should submit its data to another php page(getid.php) to select the details and display it at (product-Detail.html).

My question is how to send a value from galleryshow.php to php and at the same time display($load-$get-$post) the result in html.

The code I use in the first html page(Gallery.html) at body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.gallery_page').load('inc/galleryshow.php', function(data) {
                 $('.showd').submit(function(e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     window.location ="Product-Details.html";
                 });
            }); 
        });
</script>
```

i want to submit a value to php page to display its result in "Product-Details.html" when it loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to work on the formatting and grammar of your question

Comment: i will try english not my native Thanks

Comment: Can you post others php and html scripts ?

Comment: When people edit your post, it's to help you. If they're not changing the meaning of your question, please do not reedit your post and remake the same mistakes.

Comment: I agree with talnicolas.

Comment: OK talnicolas,Thanks Shawn31313,TeChn4K i will post it

Comment: @Heba, please look into jQuery's [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit of a stab in the dark but I think you are asking about how to attach actions to content that you have just loaded before it's been rendered?
if this is right try something like this:

```
...
$(this).find('.showd').submit(function(e) {  <-- prior to appending/adding to dom
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location ="Product-Details.html";
});
...
```

failing that try:

```
...
$(this).append(data).find('.showd').submit(function(e) { <-- appending/adding to dom then finding
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location ="Product-Details.html";
});
...
```